# Back from openWRT to tp-link 3420v3 original firmware

Tags: openwrt, firmware

I have **OpenWRT** firmware on my device (**tp-link 3420v3**).
I need to back the original software and I cannot. When I try to upload the original.bin file it says invalid image and I tried TFTP then nothing happen.

 I really need to back it anyway.

Thanks, Advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing it via [OpenWRT CLI](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/user.beginner.cli), following [this](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.uninstall) instructions:

> `cd /tmp`
>
> `wget http://www.example.org/original_firmware.bin`
>
> `mtd -r write /tmp/original_firmware.bin firmware`

Answer (score 0):

Hex, you are wrong if he will do as you said, then router will bricked. For get back to original firmware set you LAN IP of PC from dynamic to static.
IP:-192.168.0.66
Netmask:-255.255.255.0
Gateway:-192.168.0.1
and then use solarwinds tftp server to do it, it will guide you to what name you have to give to original bin file.
    http://www.omnisecu.com/cisco-certified-network-associate-ccna/how-to-configure-solarwinds-tftp-server-to-backup-ios-and-configuration-files.php
This link will guide you about tftp. I think this will help you.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Why will the other command brick the router? Also, OP mentioned he had trouble using `tftp`, how would they work around that?

Comment: The Tp-link firmware contains bootloader and openwrt does not. So after upgrading to tplink to openwrt, bootloader does not changes and if you put firmware directly in openwrt, then it will brick your router and if you remove bootloader from original firmware and then you can try mtd command safely.